# Provide configureable routes in angular library

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a library which provides some predefined pages (components), which can be accessed via routes.

But currently the user of the library has to define the routes himself in one of his routing module.

Ideally i want to define the routes inside my library and use some injected configuration (e.g. `environments.ts` from the app) to configure the routes inside my library.

The user of the library would then only have to import the library's routing module inside this app module, but can configure the routes using his environments.ts

I know how to inject the `environments.ts` into my library's routing module, but since i have to use the defined routes in the `@imports: [...]` of my routing module, i cannot access it to define the routes.

Here is some example code of what i try to archive:

Library routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: environment.some_path, component: LibraryComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LibraryRoutingModule {
    public static forRoot(environment) {
        // cannot define routes in here, so this does not work
    }
}
```

App Module

```
import { LibraryRoutingModule } from 'library'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LibraryRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forchild

Comment: My problem is not about using `forRoot` or `forChild`, but about how to use the `environment` variable to define the `path` of my routes, when `environment` should be provided by the app and not the library.

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but I think you can more simply accomplish registering predefined routes using forChild

Comment: You mind attaching an example? Because i don't understand what you mean or how that would work